# Y a-t-il un nom pour désigner les mots composés de racines linguistiques hétérogènes ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, noms, linguistique

La formulation actuelle de la question a évolué suite aux réponses données. Elle s'intitulait au départ

> Quadricéphale : comment appelle-t-on ce barbarisme spécifique ?

L'exemple utilisé dans le titre de cette question, « quadricéphale », était arbitraire et j'aurais aussi bien pu choisir « théocide » , « animologue » ou « terraphobe ».

D'où une seconde formulation, plus précise :

> Y a-t-il un nom pour désigner la faute stylistique(1) consistant, lors
>   de la création d'un néologisme, à mélanger des racines 
>   hétérogènes (dans la majeure partie des cas, latines et grecques) ?

(1) Je parle de faute stylistique dans la mesure où il me parait difficile de parler de faute grammaticale, le néologisme en lui-même étant déjà en quelque sorte "en transgression" de l'usage fixé par les institutions de la langue.

J'avais pensé à « barbarisme » (voir  [la définition du CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barbarisme)), mais il m'a semblé que le terme est trop général pour le cas spécifique que je décris.

Comment: J'ai supprimé le tag "néologismes*. Peut-être devrais-je éditer le titre de la question directement pour lui substituer cette seconde version ? Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: Pour rester dans le ton, je propose de qualifier ces mots de _multiglottes_.

Comment: Excellente suggestion, j'adore les mots auto-référentiels ou auto-descriptifs, comme *suranné*, *auto-référentiel*, *entr'ouvert*, ou *eroné*. J'ajoute *multiglotte* à ma collection !

Comment: Le mot *ludothèque* est sans doute l'un des plus utilisés.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On appelle cela un [mot hybride](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hybride).

Au passage, je trouve curieux que certains français éprouvent le besoin de rejeter à tout prix des mots sous prétexte qu'ils n'obéissent pas à une telle règle de pureté. Juxtaposer une racine de l'est et une racine de l'ouest, ou une racine du nord et une racine du sud : et pourquoi pas ? Ce phénomène aurait certainement intéressé Auguste Comte, qui inventa la sociologie — et ce, bien avant qu'apparaissent non seulement la télévision et l'automobile (qui roule aux hydrocarbures), mais même la bicyclette.

Aucune institution n'a à ma connaissance érigé de règle qui exigerait que toutes les racines d'un mot proviennent de la même langue. L'Académie française, par exemple, n'émet aucun judgement (5<sup>e</sup> éd.) :

> HYBRIDE. adj. des 2 g. Il se dit Des mots tirés de deux Langues, et il s'est dit dans son origine des animaux nés de deux espèces différentes, tels que les mulets, les léopards, etc. Choléramorbus est un mot hybride.

Même le très tatillon Littré ne s'offusque aucunement :

> 3. Terme de grammaire. Mots hybrides, mots composés d'éléments provenant de langues différentes.

Un barbarisme, au sens étymologique du terme, c'est un mot qui n'est pas grec. Ou, à l'extrême rigueur, qui n'est ni grec ni latin. Le français en regorge.

Comment: Le choix peu judicieux de mon expression *faute stylistique* a écorné le sens de mon propos : à titre personnel je ne considère pas qu'il faille rejeter ces mots, bien au contraire. J'entendais *faute* au sens de rupture avec une règle instituée, sans aucun jugement moral ou esthétique. Mon erreur aura été de postuler que les différentes instances de la langue (notamment l'Académie Française) étaient hostiles par principe à ce type de constructions. J'accepte tout-à-fait le terme *hybride*.

Comment: Les léopards ne sont pas des hybrides à ma connaissance.

Comment: @Knu Tu as raison, c'est un bug du dictionnaire de l'Académie v5. Vu que le bug était corrigé dans la v8, je pense que ce n'est pas la peine de le signaler.

Answer (score 6):

Pourquoi chercher dans le néologique homme de paille qu'il est facile de dénigrer? *Télévision, automobile, hexadécimal, homosexuel, monoculture, neurotransmetteur, sociopathe, bicyclette, hydravion* et *vexillologie* sont tous autant de termes bien établis que personne de sensé ne combat plus (en présumant qu'ils aient jamais été combattus avec la virulence qu'on oppose à *horribilité* — que j'aime bien, personnellement — ou *alunir*).

En ce qui concerne la question terminologique, étonnamment (étant donné le plaisir pervers que les académiciens semblent éprouver à nommer des erreurs), il ne semble pas y avoir de terme commun. Grevisse (14e ed., §185) parle de *formation mixtes*, mais je suis plutôt du côté de [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word) ou [Henriette Walter](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/rbph_0035-0818_2006_num_84_3_5036) en faveur d'*hybride*.

Comment: Les mots déjà usités et établis cités au début de votre réponse ont pourtant tous, par définition, été des néologismes à un moment, si vous me pardonnez ce sophisme bien intentionné. Je veux dire que cela ne répond pas - ou pas encore - à la question. Merci en revanche pour la pertinence de la remarque, qui me fait comprendre que j'ai peut-être trop restreint la formulation de la question. Et j'aime assez votre *hybride*. Jusqu'à éventuelle meilleure trouvaille, je le considère comme meilleur candidat.

Answer (score 1):

Existe en grammaire le concept d’*hétéroclisie* que le TLFi déffinit comme :

> GRAMM. [En parlant d'un mot] Dont la déclinaison, la conjugaison ne suit pas la règle ordinaire. *En grammaire traditionnelle, on dit d'un mot qu'il est hétéroclite quand son paradigme flexionnel est emprunté à plusieurs racines; ainsi, le verbe aller emprunte ses racines à va-, all-, i-* (*Ling*.1972).

Mais l’hétéroclisie est une qualité grammaticale dérrivationnelle, non terminologique. Cela dit, elle tient de l’étymologie.