# Quel mot pour dire qu'on utilise le clavier en positionnant mal ses mains ? Exemple : « lol » qui devient « kik »

Tags: informatique, demande-de-mot

Y a-t-il un terme pour désigner le fait de taper au clavier en ayant les mains mal positionnées (et décalées d'une touche) ?

Ça m'arrive assez facilement sur des mots très courts, quand ma main est décalée d'une lettre vers la gauche, ce qui fait que *lol* devient *kik*, ou que la commande `cd` devient `vf`.

Comment: Il faut bien avouer que *kik* rend assez mal l'hilarité... kik

Comment: Faut-il distinguer quelles mains sont affectées, et de quel côté elle se dirigent? (En passant, lol devient kik vers la gauche, pas vers la droite)

Comment: En tout cas si ça reproduit souvent, tu pourras toujours dire que tu es [erratippexodactylographisique](http://www.cledut.net/xylo.htm).

Comment: @Evpok Je lis ton commentaire à l'instant... « tiens qu'est-ce que c'est que ce lien? » ... je clique. Et hop, mon après-midi de travail qui fout le camp. Mon patron ne te remercie pas.

Comment: Quelle horreur, que ce mot mal formé qui mélange racine latine et racines grecques ! Le terme correct est sfalmappexodactylographisique ; un enfant sait qu'erreur se dit en grec σφάλμα. :)

Comment: @MarkThorin Quelle horreur? [vraiment](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/y-a-t-il-un-nom-pour-designer-les-mots-composes-de-racines-linguistiques-heterog)? ;-)

Comment: Et si je ne me trompe,  le site en question me paraît plus être dans une optique "Oulipesque", dès lors tous les barbarismes sont autorisés...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un mot unique pour désigner le phénomène, je ne vois pas. Mais, puisque l'ambiance semble être aux propositions libres, on pourrait éventuellement employer :

> taper/frapper *en décalé*

ou peut-être tout simplement **un décalage de frappe** ?

Pas extrêmement concis dans l'absolu, mais ça reste relativement court quand même. Non ?

(Dans un contexte plus détendu, et par analogie avec l'expression *ne pas avoir les yeux en face des trous*, on peut même sacrifier la concision et opter pour *ne pas avoir les doigts en face des touches*…)

Comment: Sans plus de contexte « décalé » évoque pour moi un décalage dans le temps et pas dans l'espace.

Comment: En effet, c'est une ambiguité possible. Il reste à voir si cela invalide la proposition.

Comment: Voire un décalage alphabétique, ou bien dans l'ordre de quelque chose (mains, touches…) Pas convaincu.

Answer (score 6):

Sur le modèle de [dysphasie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphasie), pourquoi pas le néologisme *dysdactylie*?

Comment: Si on tape (ah ah) dans les néologismes, j'ai entendu *lapsus clavieri* aussi...

Comment: +1 sans compter le mélange phonique: didactyle : deux doigts, entendu dix dactycles pour un decadactyle des membres supérieurs

Comment: "Dysdactylie" n'est pas un néologisme, c'est une déformation congénitale ou génétique de la main; "clavieri", ce n'est pas du latin : le mot "clavierus" n'existe pas.

Comment: "Dysdactylographie" serait un néologisme correctement formé.

Answer (score 6):

Un cas particulier de [**lapsus clavis**](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article79).

Comment: Belle trouvaille plussoyée illico presto

Answer (score 5):

Il y a bien un mot pour une inversion de lettre, il s'agit d'une **coquille**, autrement dit une faute de frappe (cf. [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coquille_%28typographie%29)).

Dans le cas de `cd`/`vf`, il s'agit d'une double coquille dans un shell... *kik*

Comment: +1 pour la coquille dans le shell ^^

Answer (score 4):

Il semble que vous avez donné la réponse : *avoir les mains décalées sur le clavier*, et, d'après vos exemples, il semble que vous ayez tendance à resserrer l'espace entre elles, donc, à *avoir les mains trop rapprochées*.

On pourrait inventer l'expression :

> avoir les doigts qui louchent sur le clavier.

Comment: Ou bien `avoir les doigts qui ont fourché` :)

Answer (score 4):

Continuons dans les analogies avec des expressions déjà établies, on pourrait inventer

> avoir les doigts à côté de la touche / des touches

en référence à *être à côté de la plaque*

On pourrait aussi se baser sur *marcher à côté de ses pompes* et dire

> taper/frapper à côté de ses touches

Comment: +1 mais plutôt avoir *les doigts à coté des touches* (comme le familier *marcher à coté de ses pompes*)

Answer (score 3):

Quand je travaillais dans l'édition, on parlais de *typo*.

Mais cela désignait toute faute de frappe, par opposition à une faute d'orthographe. C'est-à-dire un mot qui aurait été écrit juste si *les doigts n'avaient pas fourchés* accidentellement.

On distinguait :

- les *décalages* (s pour a),
- les *doublettes* (as pour a),
- les *doulblons* ou *pllrrr* (aaaaa pour a),
- les *shifts* (A ou select-all pour a),
- les *inversions* (as pour sa, plus fréquent au clavier qu'à la plume),
- Sans oublier les *excuses*, parce qu'il faut bien le reconnaitre, un typo c'est tout de même 
  moins grave qu'une vraie faute d'orthographe.

Comment: Bel exemple de retour d’expérience

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est peut-être pas le terme correct (confer les autres réponses pour ça), mais l'utilisation la plus répandue est probablement **une faute de frappe**.