# On parle de "lapsus linguae", de "lapsus calumni", mais ... sur un clavier ?

Tags: informatique

Étymologiquement, clavier vient du latin *clavis*, clef, dont le génitif pluriel est *clavium*.

Y a-t-il moins pédant que "*lapsus clavium*" ? Ce serait bien utile, car je commets énormément de *lapsi* de ce genre.

Bien sûr, il existe "faute de frappe". :)

Comment: Question intéressante. Peut-être à fusionner avec [celle-ci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/quel-mot-pour-dire-quon-utilise-le-clavier-en-positionnant-mal-ses-mains-exem)? Voir notamment dans les réponses, *lapsus clavis*.

Comment: Pourquoi pas ? J'ai regardé ce lien et y ai fait trois commentaires, l'un par plaisanterie pour une réponse elle-même humoristique, deux sérieux ; "lapsus clavis" est erroné, car le génétif de clavis (= une touche) est identique, mais seulement au singulier. Si l'on ne prend pas ma question pour le canular qu'elle voulait être, la seule forme que je propose est correcte ; mais bien sûr "faute de frappe" est le meilleur choix.

Comment: Soit dit en passant, il me semble que ce serait plus *lapsus clavum*.

Comment: Jamais entendu parler de "lapsus calumni". Il s'agit probablement d'un jeu de mots, la formule correcte étant "lapsus calami".

Comment: @Lepressentiment: pour ce genre de question/remarque merci de ne pas utiliser un flag. Il est possible d'en discuter sur le chat, ou de demander à l'auteur directement si c'est bien ce qu'il a voulu écrire avec un commentaire (qui pourra être supprimé par la suite).

Comment: Mon opinion est que _lapsus digiti_ est plutôt pas mal...